# qemu issue on Chromebook

Tags: debian, software-installation, qemu, chrome-book

I'm running Debian 10 on a Chromebook and I am trying to install and run different OS's on it. So I'm trying to use `qemu`.

When I enter

```
apt-get install qemu
```

I don't think it installed perfectly because there is no qemu app in my launcher, and because it gave me an error, here is all of the code:

```
root@penguin:/home/pablog22# apt-get install qemu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
qemu is already the newest version (1:3.1+dfsg-8+deb10u7).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up lightdm-login-chromiumos (1.0) ...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    40  100    40    0     0    144      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   145
Downloading: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Linux_ChromiumOS/84b76aa34b7ee89ea7b44af59239f6729aa53ab5/chrome-linux.zip
ZIP: /tmp/fileolA6K1.zip
Warning: Illegal date format for -z, --time-cond (and not a file name). 
Warning: Disabling time condition. See curl_getdate(3) for valid date syntax.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   263  100   263    0     0    977      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   977
Archive:  /tmp/fileolA6K1.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /tmp/fileolA6K1.zip or
        /tmp/fileolA6K1.zip.zip, and cannot find /tmp/fileolA6K1.zip.ZIP, period.
dpkg: error processing package lightdm-login-chromiumos (--configure):
 installed lightdm-login-chromiumos package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 9
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lightdm-login-chromiumos
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What do I do?

Comment: Good question. let me add all of the code that it gave me.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I don't think it installed perfectly because there is no qemu app in my launcher, and because it gave me an error.

Answer (score 1):

qemu is installed, hence:

```
qemu is already the newest version (1:3.1+dfsg-8+deb10u7).
```

If you want to check it is installed, you can run:

```
apt list --installed qemu
```

qemu is a command line tool. It does not have a graphical front-end by default, which is why you will not see it in your desktop launcher. This [Arch Linux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU#Graphical_front-ends_for_QEMU) describes some options for graphical front-ends for qemu that you can install, to make things easier.

However, if your Chromebook is ARM-based, be prepared that you might be disappointed with the performance you will get with virtual machines. I use Arch Linux on an armv7 Chromebook myself. I have tried installing VMs on it, but the performance I got was very bad (i.e. barely useable). My understanding is that armv7 doesn't include much in the way of hardware support for virtualization, which means you cannot use KVM. Without KVM, you can expect virtual machine performance to be pretty bad, especially if you are trying to emulate a different architecture (i.e. x86).

This error messages in your apt log seem to relate to a different package: `lightdm-login-chromiumos`. I am not sure why this package is on your system, but a quick web search suggests it allows you to log in to ChromiumOS from lightdm. It seems to not be fully installed, so if your Debian seems to be working and you don't think you need it, then it can probably be safely removed. I would recommend you back up your critical data first though.